# Is there a way to export an ActiveRecord object to seeds.rb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Is it possible to export data from a database, or run something like Person.find(1).to_seed and copy the output from console into the seeds.rb file?

Answer (score 8):

Yes.

Here's a gem – https://github.com/rroblak/seed_dump — that does exactly that.

Comment: This looks promising. Thank for sharing.

Answer (score 3):

Try using [seed-fu](https://github.com/mbleigh/seed-fu). You can give [SeedFu::Writer](https://github.com/mbleigh/seed-fu/blob/master/lib/seed-fu/writer.rb) a CSV file which will be used to generate a file in the seeds.rb "format". Of course using some database tool you would need to export the database table into a CSV file.

Answer (score 1):

No not really. But you can write code that could do that!

Strategy would be to dump out your database entries in YAML and read that YAML in seed.rb.
Another strategy is to of course write code that generates seed.rb.

Seems like a very typical need. I'm havent come across a gem or something that already does that.

Answer (score 1):

A nice snippet of code that I have found to address this is a rake task from Jesse Newland:

http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/3393

```
namespace :db do
  namespace :fixtures do
    desc 'Create YAML test fixtures from data in an existing database. Defaults to development database. Set RAILS_ENV to override.'
    task :dump => :environment do
      sql  = "SELECT * FROM %s"
      skip_tables = ["schema_info"]
      ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(:development)
      (ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables - skip_tables).each do |table_name|
        i = "000"
        File.open("test/fixtures/#{table_name}.yml", 'w') do |file|
          data = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_all(sql % table_name)
          file.write data.inject({}) { |hash, record|
            hash["#{table_name}_#{i.succ!}"] = record
            hash
          }.to_yaml
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

After you get your exported fixtures in YAML you can just run some regular expressions to format them correctly for a seeds file. This would probably be a good snippet of code to use as a basis for building a rake task for exporting a seed file.

Answer (score 0):

Open Rails console and use this trick:

```
puts name_of_your_.attributes.to_yaml
```